# Show JavaScript date - datetimeoffset(7) in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

The date is stored in the database as datetimeoffset(7).
The MVC controller gets the date from the database in the format "10/8/2015 6:05:12 PM -07:00" and passes it to the view as it is.  I am trying to convert it to the correct date to show that in the view as mm/dd/yyy by doing the following:

```
var myDate = "10/8/2015 6:05:12 PM -07:00";
var newDate = New Date(myDate);
```

Then I'm formatting it to mm/dd/yyyy format after extracting the day, month and year.

IE11 and Safari do not like this and show error "Invalid date" in the console at the line

```
 var newDate = New Date(myDate)
```

Chrome or Firefox doesn't show any problems.

Now I know that "10/8/2015 6:05:12 PM -07:00" is not a valid datestring. So my question is, how to handle this situation so all major browsers will show the correct date?

Comment: "New" is a typo, it should be "new"

Comment: "how to handle this situation" my suggestion would be to write a JSON version of your .NET object in the response and then parse it in JS

Comment: out of curiosity, what data type do you use to represent the date at the controller level?

Answer (score 0):

This function should work, I'm aware it needs some refactoring but it may be a good starting point.

```
function readDate(inputDate) {
            // extract the date that can be parsed by IE ("10/8/2015 6:05:12 PM")
            // and the timezone offset "-07:00"
            var parsedDate = /([\s\S]*?)\s*([+-][0-9\:]+)$/.exec(inputDate);

            //create new date with  "datetimeoffset" string
            var dt = new Date(parsedDate[1]);

            // get millisecs
            var localTime = dt.getTime();

            // get the offset in millisecs
            // notice the conversion to milliseconds
            // the variable "localTzOffset" can be negative 
            // because the standar (http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)
            var localTzOffset = dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

            // to get UTC time 
            var utcTime  = localTime + localTzOffset;

            // extract hours and minutes difference 
            // for given timezone
            var parsed  = /([+-][0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)/.exec(parsedDate[2]);
            var hours   = parseInt(parsed[1]);
            var minutes = parseInt(parsed[2]);

            // convert extracted difference to milliseconds
            var tzOffset = Math.abs(hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 60 * 1000);

            // taking into accout if negative
            tzOffset = hours > 1 ? tzOffset : tzOffset * -1;

            // construct the result Date
            return new Date(utcTime + tzOffset);
}
```

Usage:

```
var date = readDate("10/8/2015 6:05:12 PM -07:00");
```